# MySql only returns 1 result in php

Tags: php, mysql

I've got this PHP code:

```
$queryGO = "SELECT * from (SELECT g.go as GO, a.gen as Gen, g.descr as Description 
                            FROM geneOntology g, $tabla a where g.go=a.go) resultado 
                            WHERE resultado.go = '$go'";

$result = mysql_query($queryGO, $db);
$items = mysql_affected_rows($db);
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

It constructs me this query:

```
SELECT * from ( SELECT g.go as GO, a.gen as Gen, g.descr as Description
FROM geneOntology g, goHuman a where g.go=a.go) resultado 
WHERE resultado.go = 'GO:0000012'
```

In PHP, it returns only 1 item (and row) but if I execute the query directly in terminal, it throws 15 registers:

```
+------------+--------+----------------------------+
| GO         | Gen    | Description                |
+------------+--------+----------------------------+
| GO:0000012 | APLF   | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | APTX   | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | E9PIP4 | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | E9PJ82 | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | E9PLZ0 | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | E9PP57 | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | E9PQ18 | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | H0YEW9 | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | LIG4   | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | M0R2N6 | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | Q6ZNB5 | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | SIRT1  | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | TDP1   | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | TNP1   | single strand break repair |
| GO:0000012 | XRCC1  | single strand break repair |
+------------+--------+----------------------------+
15 rows in set (0,04 sec)
```

I cannot see what is happening. Indeed, I have similar code in other php action and it executes de query ok... Could you help me?

Thanks in advance! Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Loop through your return with a while loop, you're only returning one row:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
   print_r($row);
}
```

---

Please stop using mysql_* functions. These extensions have been removed in PHP 7. Learn about prepared statements for PDO and MySQLi and consider using PDO, it's really pretty easy.

Comment: @user3118279  And if you switch to PDO you will also be able to use `fetchAll()` to achieve what you are trying to achieve currently with an API that doesn't support it.

Comment: Ok, I'm gonna try it. Anyway, $items = mysql_affected_rows($db),  should not return 15 instead 1?

Comment: mysql_affected_rows doesn't work for SELECT queries, check the docs.